# group theory - function into function

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

There is a group $A$ and it has $12$ elements, lets look at all the functions $A$ to $A$ which has the next trait: $a\in A,    f(f(f(a)))=a$,       but ,  $f(f(a))\neq a$.

1. Prove its an Injective and Surjective function.
2. How many functions like that exist?

please advice.

Comment: Where are you using that $A$ is a group. Do you just mean a set, or is $f$ supposed to be a homomorphism?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If $f$ is a homomorphism, then $f(f(1_A))=1$. I'm not sure though because the OP didn't use quantifiers.

Comment: Yeah, my main point is really that the problem is poorly formed. My guess is that nothing about the problem requires $A$ to be a group, just a set of $12$ elements, but I was trying to figure out if there was a way that he could really need $A$ to be a group.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh I see, and judging by the OPs only other question I think you might be right, he means that $A$ is a set.

Comment: @Daniel pltk Do you know the difference between a set and a group?

Comment: @GitGud It seems like poor translation to me, he's probably studying set theory. Also, since the function needs to be invertible, it seems that he means $\forall a$.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez That might be the case, yes.

Comment: f: A → A , by the way this question is taken from academic exam and this exact formation was given.

Comment: @Danielpltk In english?

Comment: No. And i think Git Gud and Thomas are right. A is a set of 12 elements which are natural numbers

Comment: @Danielpltk: It doesn't matter at all what the elements of $A$ are, just that there are 12 of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the comments, we assume that $A$ is only a set.

1. Since $f\circ f\circ f=id_A$, we have that $f\circ f=f^{-1}$, so that $f$ has inverse, so it is a bijection.
2. This is the point where group theory enters. So, $f$ is a permutation on $A$, that is, $f\in S_{12}$, and has order $3$, that is, it is a union of disjoint cycles of length $3$ (can consist of $1,2,3$ or $4$ disjoint cycles of length $3$). Now count these..

Comment: +1 for pointing out what this actually has to do with group theory.

Comment: If the condition $f(f(a)) \neq a$ is for all $a \in A$ then in the answer of Berci you only have to consider the permutations that have 4 disjoint cycles of lenght 3. I wrote this answer because I can't comment Berci's answer.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. Thanks.